# Build ASP.NET Core from source error MSB4036: The "GenerateFileFromTemplate" task was not found

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I build ASP.NET Core [from the source](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c2488eead6ead7208f543d0a57104b5d167b93f9/docs/BuildFromSource.md), [main branch](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/c2488eead6ead7208f543d0a57104b5d167b93f9) on win11. I execute **restore.cmd** got an error:

```
aspnetcore\eng\tools\GenerateFiles\GenerateFiles.csproj(37,5): error MSB4036: The "GenerateFileFromTemplate" task was not found. Check the following: 1.) The name of
the task in the project file is the same as the name of the task class. 2.) The task class is "public" and implements the Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask interface. 3.) The task is correctly declared with <Usin
gTask> in the project file, or in the *.tasks files located in the "C:\Users\chiwenjun\Documents\Sources\github\aspnetcore\.dotnet\sdk\8.0.100-preview.5.23275.15" directory.
```

How can I solve this problem, thanks!

Comment: I can't reproduce. Since there's no similar issue. How about delete and retry all steps.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem and recorded it at [github](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/48629)